# CRA inside docker container with typescript takes very long time

Tags: reactjs, typescript, build, create-react-app, webpack-production

When no other builds are running it takes 40minutes on our server. The project is pretty large with many the output is 4K. My question is if this is normal/expected? Because I've seen posts of others complaining about like 10min run times.

EDIT:

Majority of the time is in: "Creating an optimized production build..."

If not anything I can do? Any gotchas I may missed? Thanks alot.

Server specs:
CPU: Intel Xeon 1225v3
RAM: 4GB

Comment: Can you see on the console which part the build seems to be getting stuck on?

Comment: @Paddy I added it in an edit

Comment: Are you using react-scripts package for your build? If so try updating it to latest version. They are always trying to make the builds faster.

Comment: I'm on version 2.1 so I could update to 3, but there breaking changes i wil need to handle.

Comment: I'd give it a try. I think they changed the version of Webpack that react-scripts they used when they moved to version 3 and it sped up builds.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Definetely worth trying.

Comment: No problem. I've made that suggestion an answer. If it works come back and mark it as accepted answer. I'm trying to accumulate internet points :P

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your version of react-scripts. I think they changed the version of Webpack that react-scripts uses when they moved to version 3 and it sped up builds.